# не могу правильно написать условие на php

Tags: php, pdo

я относительно не давно начал учить php и как результат решил написать для себя небольшой слкдаской учет, с своеиобразным вычетом стоимости в зависимости от выбранного объема.

у нас есть такие строки в таблице :

price_1(50р)  price_2(100р) price_3(150р) price_4(200р) price_5(250р)

если товар в корзине 1 или 49 (то брать цену из таблицы cena -> price_1) если товара 50 или 99 (то брать цену из таблицы cena -> price_2) итд

Comment: И вопрос конкретный какой?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: вопрос конкретно не могу это реализовать на php

Comment: @zortwarut, `echo 'price_' . (~~($n / 50) + 1);` где `$n` - это кол-во в корзине. Хотя не уверен, что хранение данных и все возможные варианты у вас продуманы. Взять хотя бы случай, если в корзине товаров будут 500, а поля `price_11` у вас не существует.

Comment: price_11 и ненадо, к примеру все что больше 250 будет считаться за price_5

Comment: но с Вашего примера не понял, как взять значение с бд

Comment: Я показал вам, как можно сформировать название нужного поля. Теперь вы можете или подставить это значение в запрос, или выбрать в запросе все колонки `price_N`, а значение взять из нужной, с помощью всё того же сгенерированного названия.

Comment: Наверное стоит отметить что я вообше только только начинаюший, ученик , меленнььький такой =)

Comment: главное шляпу вида `~~($n/50)` в живой код не тащите никогда. Есть нормальные способы получения целой части из дроби, которые будут нормально читаемы и понимаемы любым разработчиком.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему бы не вывести из БД все Ваши прайсы для начала

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM price");
$sql->execute([]);
$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

далее смотрим какое кол-во товара у вас в корзине ... думаю тут проблем у вас не будет ... и это количество записываем в переменную к примеру $count. Ну и далее прогоняем через условия к примеру

```
if($count >=1 && $count <=49){
  $price = $sql["price1"];
} else if($count >=50 && $count <=99){
  $price = $sql["price2"];
} // и т.д.
```

Ну и потом выводим переменную $price туда куда Вам нужно